# My dash app is opening as an output of a cell in jupiter notebook instead of a link to another page

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In one computer it was working just fine but I don't know what happened in the other one.[this is how it is opening but usually it opens just a link to another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFSr3.png)

I already tried installing all the packages again but nothing worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Just encountered this error as well.